# jQuery division visibility hidden is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#id_btnquizzestwo").click(function() {
    $temp = $("#rightsideeightone").is(":visible");     
    if($temp) {
        $("#rightsideeightone").css('display') = 'none';    
    }
})
```

The rightsideeightone division is not being hidden.

What to do ?

```
$("#id_btnquizzestwo").click(function() {
    $temp = $("#rightsideeightone").is(":visible");
    //alert($temp);

    if($temp) {
        $("#rightsideeightone").hide();         
    }

    $temp2 = $("#rightsideeighttwo").is(":hidden");
    //alert($temp2);

    if($temp2) {
        $("#rightsideeighttwo").show();
    }
})
```

I tried this, the rightsideeighttwo is not being visible. Initialy the rightsideeightone is visible and the rightsideeighttwo is hidden.

```
<div id="rightsideeight" >
    <div id="id_pollsquizzes" >
        <?php echo '<ul>'; ?>
        <?php
            echo '<li>';
            echo $this->Form->button('Polls',array('type'=>'button','id'=>'id_btnpollstwo'));
            echo '</li>';
            echo '&nbsp&nbsp';

            echo '<li>';
            echo $this->Form->button('Quizzes',array('type'=>'button','id'=>'id_btnquizzestwo'));
            echo '</li>';
            echo '&nbsp&nbsp';
        ?>

    </div>

    <div id="rightsideeightone" style="visibility: visible" >
            ......................
    </div>

    <div id="rightsideeighttwo" style="visibility: hidden" >
            ......................
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I have edited the original post/question and the html code to understand.

Comment: What html is generated by this string? echo $this->Form->button('Polls',array('type'=>'button','id'=>'id_btnpollstwo')); And besides you haven't closed ul element.

Comment: @Webars, is this what you are looking for ? http://jsfiddle.net/LQg7W/85/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line

```
$("#rightsideeightone").css('display') = 'none';
```

is incorrect. To change a style property, use this syntax:

```
$("#rightsideeightone").css('display','none');
```

Checking the visibility isn't necessary - if the element $("#rightsideeightone") is already hidden then hiding it again has no effect, so your function can be written as:

```
$("#id_btnquizzestwo").click(function() {
        $("#rightsideeightone").css('display','none');
});
```

Comment: I have edited the original question/post. The rightsideeighttwo is not being visible. Initialy the rightsideeightone is visible and the rightsideeighttwo is hidden.

Comment: I think $temp2 = $("#rightsideeighttwo").is(":hidden"); will always return false: shouldn't it be  $temp2 = $("#rightsideeighttwo").is(":visible"); ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the `$temp` variable equals false you could try:

```
$('#rightsideeightone').hide();
```

Comment: I have edited the original question/post. The rightsideeighttwo is not being visible. Initialy the rightsideeightone is visible and the rightsideeighttwo is hidden.

Answer (score 3):

All three explanation should work. But just for clarification:

Using this:

```
$("#rightsideeightone").css('display') = 'none';
```

Isn't working due to `.css('display')` this is a getter. As in get the current value of the `display` property. So what you are basically doing here is first getting the value (say 'block') and then try to assign a new value ('none') to it. It would be the equivalent of: (just for explanation, doesn't actually work):

```
'block' = 'none';
```

You need to set the value of display **on the element** not just overwrite the propert you get. Hence use the jQuery setter:

```
$("#rightsideeightone").css('display','none'); 
// OR
$("#rightsideeightone").css({ display: 'none' });
```

I prefer the later one.

Hope I explained it more the confused it :)

Comment: $("#rightsideeighttwo").css({ visibility: 'visible' });  i can't make it visible.

Comment: `display` and `visibility` are to different properties. If you use `display: 'none'` use `display: 'inline` or `display: 'block` to show it. And so, if you use `visibility` switch between `visible/hidden`.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/LQg7W/89/

```
.visible { display: block; }
.hidden { display: none; }

$("#id_btnquizzestwo").click(function() {

  if( $("#rightsideeightone").is(".visible") )
    $("#rightsideeightone").removeClass("visible").addClass('hidden');

  if( $("#rightsideeighttwo").is(".hidden") )
    $("#rightsideeighttwo").removeClass("hidden").addClass('visible');

});
```

Comment: I have edited the original question/post. The rightsideeighttwo is not being visible. Initialy the rightsideeightone is visible and the rightsideeighttwo is hidden.

Comment: $("#rightsideeighttwo").css({ visibility: 'visible' }); it's not working it's not being visible.